# Making my coffee maker smarter

Tags: relay, home-automation

I'm planning to add a WiFi-enabled relay ([Shelly 1](https://shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/devices/shelly-1/)) to my coffee maker for some fun home automation. In this case, the coffee maker has a tactile switch labeled "brew now". I understand the approach of using a transistor to connect a relay to the switch, such that the relay can emulate pressing the button.

However, I would like to send the signal from the switch to the relay, so that it works like a momentary switch, with different functionality based upon how many times / how long it's pressed. The basic functions would be:

1. Single, short press = trigger automation for delayed brewing
2. Single, long press = initiate brewing now

So in this case, I do need the relay to send the signal to the machine, but I also need to intercept the signal from the switch and send it to the relay. This is where I'm stuck. Images included below.

Any suggestions?

[image: Side a]

[image: Side b]

Comment: How smart? Be careful: https://youtu.be/LRq_SAuQDec

Comment: You'd need to break the link from the switch to the rest of the machine and put your smart control logic in between.

Comment: @SolarMike I see you are a man of culture.

Comment: @finbarr that is what I thought but wanted to be sure

Comment: Be very careful! Circuits inside a coffee maker are often not insulated from the mains.